# write to file in SQL Server on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I am testing SQL Server on Linux.
I am trying to output a table from SQL Server to a file.
Since xp_cmdshell is not available on Linux I cannot use BCP directly from SQL Server Management Studio. 
How can I write to file using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Maybe wait a little while MS will provide SQLAgent and then do it via Job.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the results of your query in your Windows machine, you can always write to file from SSMS by selecting the "Results to File" button, or pressing Ctrl-Shift-F.

If you need the file to be in a specific format, you can go to Tools>Options>Query Results>SQL Server>Results to Text and then select your desired format on the top-right corner of the window.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help me much. I would like to have a stored procedure that can save contents of a given table to a file. I used to do that a lot using xp_cmdshell.

Comment: I understand now. One thing you can do is create a script that uses SQLCMD to run a query and output the results to a file:
`$ sqlcmd -S your_server -U sa -P your_password -Q "SELECT * FROM test_table" -o your_output_file.txt`